# Arduino SIM900 GSM how to Join Char on String

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, gsm, gprs

I am currently making an Arduino project with GSM900 GSM GPRS. In this project, I have to receive data sent from a phone. I could easily receive data with a single character, but I can`t join does character to obtain a full word (String). I have to use this full word inside an If statement if this word equals to that other word (string), make something...

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

// Configure software serial port
SoftwareSerial SIM900(7, 8);
//Variable to save incoming SMS characters
char incoming_char=0;
String newchar = "";

void setup() {
  // Arduino communicates with SIM900 GSM shield at a baud rate of 19200
  SIM900.begin(19200);
  Serial.begin(19200); 

  // Give time to your GSM shield log on to network
  delay(20000);

  // AT command to set SIM900 to SMS mode
  SIM900.print("AT+CMGF=1\r"); 
  delay(100);
  // Set module to send SMS data to serial out upon receipt 
  SIM900.print("AT+CNMI=2,2,0,0,0\r");
  delay(100);
}

void loop() {
  if(SIM900.available() >0) {
    incoming_char=SIM900.read(); 
    Serial.print(incoming_char); 
  }
}
```

I tried putting this command on the the if statement inside the loop, but after i tried comparing the words, it wouldnt work.

```
void loop() {
  if(SIM900.available() >0) {
    incoming_char=SIM900.read();
    newString = incoming_char + "";
    Serial.print(incoming_char); 
  }
  if (newString == "Test"){
       Serial.println("It worked");
    }
}
```

The output that i get from the Monitor Serial is this:
+CMT: "+myNumber","","19/09/20,16:31:05-12"
Test

Comment: newString += incoming_char and not newString = incoming_char + ""; the second one will contain always the last char you got from your module, the first one add each new char to the string

Comment: The output that I get from the Monitor Serial is this:
+CMT: "+<myNumber>","","19/09/20,16:31:05-12"
Test

Comment: if the size of (+CMT: "+<myNumber>","","19/09/20,16:31:05-12" ) is fixed then Record characters only after that number is reached

Comment: How could I make that? The size is fixed.

Comment: try using "endwith" function or using a counter

Comment: It would be like this?:

void loop() {
  if(SIM900.available() >0) {
    incoming_char=SIM900.read();
    
    if (incoming_char.endsWith(" \" ")){
    newString += incoming_char;
    }
    
    Serial.print(incoming_char); 
  }
}

Comment: yes this probably will work. but why not directly change newString == "Test" to newString.endsWith("Test")

Comment: It Worked, Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
void loop() {
    if (SIM900.available() >0) {
        incoming_char=SIM900.read();
        newString += incoming_char;
        Serial.print(incoming_char); 
    }

    if (newString.endsWith("Test")) {
        Serial.println("It worked");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For does who are wondering how it finished:
Thanks to phoenixstudio...

```
void loop() {
  if(SIM900.available() >0) {
    incoming_char=SIM900.read();
    newString += incoming_char;
    Serial.print(incoming_char);
  }

  if (newString.endsWith("Test1")){
    Serial.println("Worked1"); 
  }
  if (newString.endsWith("Test2")){
    Serial.println("Worked2"); 
  }
  if (newString.endsWith("Test3"){
    Serial.println("Worked3"); 
  }
}
```